# How do I make my app respond to a format based on a querystring parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource, actioncontroller

For example, I would like

> /apples/123?_format=json

to act like

> /apples/123.json

where it renders the *.json.* templates, executes respond_to {|format| format.json {...}}, etc.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but what's wrong with doing it right?

Comment: Unfortunately the app needs to implement the FHIR standard, which takes format in the query string as an option.

http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/http.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to disable Rails' automatic handling of the `.ext` format:

```
constraints format: false do
  resources :apples
  # ...
end
```

Then, and this is a bit gross but I don't see a better way to do this at the moment, you can do the following to update ActionController on what format to serve:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_format_from_query_string

private

  def set_format_from_query_string
    request.format = params.fetch(:_format, 'json')
  end
end
```

This will allow your `respond_to` block to toggle based on the `_format` query string parameter and uses `json` as the default format.